# PHP date/strtotime converting to incorrect date

Tags: php, datetime, date, strtotime

On some occasions `data()` is converting my dates incorrectly.

My date formats look like so:
`Fri Oct 25 15:00:00 EDT 2011`

The date string comes from an external source, so I'm unable to change the format.

```
// output incorrect - Fri, 28 Oct 2011 15:00:00 -0400
date("r", strtotime("Fri Oct 25 15:00:00 EDT 2011"))

// output correct - Fri, 21 Oct 2011 15:00:00 -0400
date("r", strtotime("Fri Oct 21 15:00:00 EDT 2011"))
```

I can't figure out why just changing the day makes it fail to convert.

My end goal is to create a DateTime object but it suffers from the same problem.

```
// output - Fri Oct 28 19:00:00 EDT 2011
DateTime("Fri Oct 22 19:00:00 EDT 2011")
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark -- October 21 and 28th are Fridays, but not the 22nd or the 25th.

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing... how did I not notice that. I will have to speak with the devs of the feed. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oct 25/2011 is a tuesday. Strtotime is interpreting your date string as "what's the next friday AFTER Oct 25th", and is returning (what it thinks) is the correct answer: October 28th.

So, the GIGO rule applies. You're feeding in garbage, and wondering why you're getting garbage out.

Comment: GIGO rule is awesome. Never heard of that expression before :-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, as I said I can not change the feed but I will have to speak with the devs.

Comment: @Paramount: maybe you could change the devs then since they messed up your dates? :) BTW, you can just strip out the day out of the given dates and it will work just as good, since you have the day, month & year in it...

Comment: @Dvir Azulay Thanks. Stripping it out seems easiest, as I would just need to substr from the index of the first space.

Comment: @Paramount: Yep, a substr is definitely the easiest. strtotime is a magical function sometimes, but when it screws up, it screws up bigtime.

Answer (score 0):

The value you're passing into `strtotime` doesn't tally. There's no Friday 25th, 2011.

http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/monthly.html

Comment: @JackMurdoch Skipped October.

Answer (score 0):

`date()` works fine.
Problem is, in your examples with incorrect output specified date is **not Friday**.

You can strip out first 4 characters if it always is `Fri`.